# 3DMap object created using GIS addon is set up so that other objects cannot be displayed

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]I create 3DMAP with Blender.

I loaded a glb file in Blender, but it is not displayed.

I loaded VRgallery, which is marked in blue on the right. I have pasted the following.

Imported and selected objects are not displayed for some reason.

I tried pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to hide everything except the VRGallery.

I pressed <kbd>/</kbd> to hide all but the selection, but it didn't work.

Unity is also not displayed when importing from Asset, and I think it is the same phenomenon.

What we have tried.

1. After adding the object (VR Gallery) first,
   3DMAP (EXPORT_GOOGLE_SAT_WM.001) first.
2. After inserting 3DMAP (EXPORT_GOOGLE_SAT_WM.001), insert the object (VR Gallery).
   [image]

We found that the GoogleMAP cut-out added with addon is the reason why it is not displayed. Why is this not showing up?

[image]